# Why does DoubleStream.sum()'s result differ from straight addition?

Tags: java

I am confused. If I calculate

```
System.out.println(0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1);
```

Then I get a result of `0.9999999999999999`. But if I calculate

```
Double sum = DoubleStream.builder().add(0.1).add(0.1).add(0.1).add(0.1).add(0.1).add(0.1).add(0.1).add(0.1).add(0.1).add(0.1).build().sum();
System.out.println(sum);
```

Then I get a result of `1.0`. 
Why is there a difference?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: And keep in mind: the first line is **completely** computed by the compiler. It does constant folding and sums up these values for you. Check your byte code - you will not find an addition in there for option 1.

Comment: @GhostCat It's still a good question. Yes, floating point math is inexact, but it ought to be consistent. It's not random. What explains the difference?

Comment: @GhostCat I disagree; the question is perfectly legitimate

Comment: What's the best way to sum multiple values?

Comment: @JohnKugelman Did I say it is a bad question? Did I close vote for *dup*? Neither of that. Actually I just put up two comments.

Comment: @GhostCat I fail to see the relationship

Comment: @fge Thing is that the title directly got somebody to close-vote as "asking to recommend". And then the question doesn't show if the OP did do any research around the floating-point topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Javadoc of **[double java.util.stream.DoubleStream.sum()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#sum--)** answers your question:

> In particular, this method may be implemented using compensated summation or other technique to reduce the error bound in the numerical sum compared to a simple summation of double values.

In other words, the implementation of `sum()` doesn't have to use simple summation of double values (which can have accuracy issues, as you noticed in your first snippet), and therefore may return a [more accurate result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).

EDIT: Note that even though using `DoubleStream`'s `sum()` appears to give a more accurate result, this is an implementation detail, so it's not guaranteed by the Javadoc. Besides, simple `double` addition is more efficient, since it doesn't have the overhead of constructing a `DoubleStream`. You have to decide if you prefer potential better accuracy or performance.

Comment: I think it would be useful here to "bold" the citation; this is the crucial point

Comment: @fge I think the entire citation (or most of it) is relevant, which is why I didn't put any of it in bold. It is a short enough quote anyway.

Comment: Yes, the whole citation is relevant, but don't you think, when reading the answer "at a first glance", that the whole citation would be missed? You know how the human mind works wrt visual clues and attention span, right? :) Especially since the reflex of clicking on the javadoc link and reading _the whole javadoc_ won't be as prevalent. Well, just my opinion ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just to augment Eran's answer, internally `DoubleStream#sum` uses [Kahan Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).

Relevant parts:

```
/**
 * Incorporate a new double value using Kahan summation /
 * compensation summation.
 *
 * High-order bits of the sum are in intermediateSum[0], low-order
 * bits of the sum are in intermediateSum[1], any additional
 * elements are application-specific.
 *
 */
static double[] sumWithCompensation(double[] intermediateSum, double value) { ....
```